# Embedding PHP commands in WordPress editor HTML tab

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using Wordpress and I want to have some PHP commands executed on my page. After I paste  my HTML with embedded PHP (in HTML tab of WordPress editor), the PHP codes are automatically converted to comments!! Below is the example:

What I enter in HTML tab:

```
<div class="floated"><label for="contactName"><?php _e( 'Name', 'arizona' ); ?>*:</label>
```

What it looks like after I go to Visual tab and then come back to HTML tab:

```
<div class="floated"><label for="contactName"><!--?php _e( 'Name', 'arizona' ); ?-->*:</label>
```

It looks like the editor just accept pure HTML code and converts the rest of unknown tags to comment! If that's the case how can have/call a php page within my text!.

I need this as I want to have a contact form within an accordion slider!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a good practice, that's why it's not supported within Wordpress.

The following are considered good practices:

1. Custom Code on your Theme
2. Create a Wordpress Plugin
3. Create a Wordpress Widget

If you want a contact form consider using the Contact Form 7 Plugin.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/contact-form-7/

Which will let you add a TAG that you could use in that accordion.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a wordpress plugin to execute arbitrary php code inside a page maintained in the editor.

I've used this one before, it's not bad but once you get into anything that needs to maintain state or process forms, it can be a bit messy but certainly possible. Not a shortcoming of the plugin really, but of trying to run custom code you maintain in the page editor.  It might be better to write your custom code as a custom wordpress plugin.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/exec-php/